# Проблема с переобразованием JSON в массив

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема, имею следующий JSON:

```
[{
    "name": "Cow",
    "quantity": "199"
}, {
    "name": "Sheep",
    "quantity": "199"
}, {
    "name": "Chicken",
    "quantity": "49"
}, {
    "quantity": "Beef",
    "quantity": "149"
}, {
    "name": "Rabbit",
    "quantity": "24"
}]
```

Попытался вызвать это всё в цикле - ничего не выводило, как ни странно. Попробовал через print_r вывести одну ячейку, т.е.:

```
print_r($info[0]['name']);
```

В итоге получил ошибку:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Попробовал обратиться, как к объекту:

```
print_r($info->0->name);
```

В итоге:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так вы посмотрите что выводит `print_r( $info )`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Cow
            [quantity] => 199
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Sheep
            [quantity] => 199
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Chicken
            [quantity] => 49
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 149
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Rabbit
            [quantity] => 24
        )
)
```

Получается массив из объектов. Стало быть, к его элементам нужно обращаться так: `$info[0]->{'name'}` и т.д.

Comment: Зачем скобочки и кавычки вокруг name? Почему не `$info[0]->name`?

Comment: @Arnial В данном случае не важно в случае когда свойство будет какоенибудь типо `name-test` или `name_name` придёться через {} обращаться

Comment: О, спасибо Вам, помогло. Заодно я задам вопрос - при json_encode текст русскими буквами кодируется в кодировку типа \u0440\u0443\.Насколько понял, это номер символа в определенной кодировке. Но потом при json_decode возвращается null вместо текста, который закодирован. Возможно, нужно сделать какие-то дополнительные манипуляции?

Comment: @Felix неможет быть такого http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93ff0c1cc2886f2448f84d3184de5ea4c17a7c94

Comment: @Naumov, действительно, видимо был невнимателен и где-то допустил ошибку, спасибо за ответ. А не подскажите во что это кодируется? Для общего развития, так сказать. И отчасти, причины интересны, ведь даже если не кодировать всё отлично работает в коде. Возможно, это касается другого ЯП, где используется JSON?

Comment: @Felix Это escape последовательность юникод символов u - unicode и 8 битный код, в десятеричной системе счисления. т.е. первый бит(байт могу переврать) две цифры после u указывает на столбец, последние две цифры на строку. Если представить таблицу сиволов как матрицу.  Данный код записываеться в соответствие с ASCII 0-127. Так как в далёких временах js(json точнее) не понимал unicod символы и падал из за не валидного json. Где то так... Но я могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 4):

Преобразуйте JSON строку в массив ([doc](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)):

```
$result = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
```

Или обращайтесь к свойству объекта правильно:

```
$someName = $info->{'0'}->name;
```

Comment: ,cпасибо за Ваш ответ. В плане обращения к свойству объекта правильно - попробовал Вариант предоставленный Вами - не помогло, увы :(
А JSON я переобразовал массив, и с ним в коде и работаю, вот var_dump переобразованного массива(ниже, а то лимит):

Comment: `array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["name"]=> string(3) "Cow" ["quantity"]=> string(3) "199" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Sheep" ["quantity"]=> string(3) "199" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Chicken" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "49" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["quantity"]=> string(3) "149" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Rabbit" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "24" } }`

Comment: Потому что преобразовали не так как я советовал - получился массив объектов. Но об этом уже написали.

Comment: А вот, что касается кодирования юникода, то опция ``JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`` позволяет этого избежать: ``json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)``